# Unexpected Rust stack frames in perf script

Tags: rust, perf

I am profiling a Rust binary using `perf record` and I observe unexpected stack frames in the output of `perf script`. As a result, the flamegraph is difficult to interpret. How can I avoid these unexpected stack frames?

Profiling commands:

```bash
$ perf record -F 997 --call-graph dwarf,65528 -g -e cpu-clock /path/to/bin
$ perf script
```

In the application, `fn main` calls `fn tip_mine`. Here is a record from `perf script` which shows the expected stack frame:

```
...
56275bcc4bee stacks_inspect::tip_mine+0xd23e (inlined)
56275bcc4bee stacks_inspect::main+0xd23e (/home/igor/stacks-blockchain/target/release/stacks-inspect)
ffffffffffffffff [unknown] ([unknown])
```

Here is another record from `perf script` from the same run which shows extra stack frames between `fn main` and `fn tip_mine`:

```
...
56275bcbe20d stacks_inspect::tip_mine+0x685d (inlined)
56275bcbe20d stacks_inspect::main+0x685d (/home/igor/stacks-blockchain/target/release/stacks-inspect)
56275bc9bc42 core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once+0x2 (inlined)
56275bc9bc42 std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace+0x2 (/home/igor/stacks-blockchain/target/release/stacks-inspect)
56275bca5e68 std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}+0x8 (inlined)
56275c35dc8d core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::panicking::try::do_call+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::panicking::try+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::panic::catch_unwind+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::panicking::try::do_call+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::panicking::try+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::panic::catch_unwind+0x42d (inlined)
56275c35dc8d std::rt::lang_start_internal+0x42d (/home/igor/stacks-blockchain/target/release/stacks-inspect)
56275bcc64e7 main+0x27 (/home/igor/stacks-blockchain/target/release/stacks-inspect)
7fa0aa8b4d8f [unknown] (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
7fa0aa8b4e3f __libc_start_main+0x7f (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
56275bc5a1d4 _start+0x24 (/home/igor/stacks-blockchain/target/release/stacks-inspect)
```

Comment: Can you explain how you obtained the first stack frame?

Comment: Both stack frames come the output of `perf script`. The output is 128MB large.

Comment: Note that in second case they're not "between" - they're _below_, `stacks_inspect::main` and `stacks_inspect::tip_mine` are still next to each other. All added stack frames are either from Rust runtime - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/91ffbc43b18842594adb997c8eea8c51035bf0e1/library/std/src/rt.rs#L106 - or from libc, so I'm unsure why they sometimes don't exist.

Comment: @Cerberus good observation! Thank you for the code link! The mystery remains why these frames are added inconsistently.

Comment: Perhaps the first frame in the first stack dump:
`ffffffffffffffff [unknown] ([unknown])`
fails to resolve and actually refers to the `lang_start_internal` frames.